# How to start sql server extended events sessions using sql query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am able to create SQL Server Extended events session using sql query.
But following are the two issues i am facing while creating Extended events session using sql query

1. Extended events session gets created in disabled(stop) state.
2. .xel file is not getting created at specified location.

I noticed while creating extended events using wizard initially extended event is created in disabled(stop) state and on selecting "Start event session immeditely...." session is set to start state and .xel file is created.

I want to implement this same step using sql query.

Following is my script

```
CREATE EVENT SESSION [LoginSession_History] ON SERVER 
ADD EVENT sqlserver.connectivity_ring_buffer_recorded(
    ACTION(sqlserver.client_app_name,sqlserver.client_connection_id,sqlserver.client_hostname,sqlserver.context_info,sqlserver.database_name,sqlserver.nt_username,sqlserver.plan_handle,sqlserver.query_hash,sqlserver.query_plan_hash,sqlserver.server_principal_name,sqlserver.session_id,sqlserver.sql_text)),
ADD EVENT sqlserver.login(SET collect_options_text=(1)
    ACTION(sqlserver.client_app_name,sqlserver.client_connection_id,sqlserver.client_hostname,sqlserver.context_info,sqlserver.database_name,sqlserver.nt_username,sqlserver.plan_handle,sqlserver.query_hash,sqlserver.query_plan_hash,sqlserver.server_instance_name,sqlserver.server_principal_name,sqlserver.session_id,sqlserver.sql_text)),
ADD EVENT sqlserver.logout(
    ACTION(sqlserver.client_app_name,sqlserver.client_connection_id,sqlserver.client_hostname,sqlserver.context_info,sqlserver.database_name,sqlserver.nt_username,sqlserver.plan_handle,sqlserver.query_hash,sqlserver.query_plan_hash,sqlserver.server_instance_name,sqlserver.server_principal_name,sqlserver.session_id,sqlserver.sql_text))
ADD TARGET package0.event_file(SET filename=N'D:\Ext_Events\LoginSession_History.xel'),
ADD TARGET package0.ring_buffer
WITH (MAX_MEMORY=4096 KB,EVENT_RETENTION_MODE=ALLOW_SINGLE_EVENT_LOSS,MAX_DISPATCH_LATENCY=30 SECONDS,MAX_EVENT_SIZE=0 KB,MEMORY_PARTITION_MODE=NONE,TRACK_CAUSALITY=ON,STARTUP_STATE=ON)
GO
```

Comment: you mentioned "I am able to create SQL Server Extended events session using sql query" are you used `STATE = start;  ` while creating ?

Comment: I have used "STARTUP_STATE=ON" but not "STATE=start" which u have mentioned , where we need to add this parameter

Comment: follow this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-event-session-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: Thanks a lot , issue got fixed

Comment: Please mark my answer as accepted. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Use `STATE = start;` via altering the EVENT SESSION as next

```
-- Start the event session  
ALTER EVENT SESSION test_session  
ON SERVER  
STATE = start;  
GO
```

[Reference from official site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-event-session-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Answer (score 0):

To fix this , we need to use Alter event session command and pass STATE=start
Following is the link

https://www.concurrency.com/blog/december-2015/schedule-extended-events-session-start-or-stop

Answer (score 0):

```
STARTUP_STATE=ON
```

Refers to the state that will used when the sqlserver service instance is restarted.
It determines whether it will be auto-started or not.
Whether to set ON|OFF depends on the type of event tracing you want to perform & whether you want it activate across recycles.

An invasive trace that consumes many cpu cycles whilst logging lots of detail would be very unwelcome at startup in most places.